# Making a program recursively call itself in Python

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, python-3.x, recursion

I have written a simple script, it runs on a folder and will cycle through all of the files in a folder to do some processing (the actual processing is unimportant).

I have a folder. This folder contains multiple different folders. Inside these folders are a variable number of files, on which I want to run the script I have written. I'm struggling to adapt my code to do this.

So previously, the file structure was :

```
Folder
  Html1
  Html2
  Html3
  ...
```

Now it is :

```
Folder
  Folder1
    Html1
  Folder2
    Html2
    Html3
```

I still want to run the code on all of the HTMLs though.

Here is my attempt at doing this, which results in

```
error on line 25, in CleanUpFolder
    orig_f.write(soup.prettify().encode(soup.original_encoding))
TypeError: encode() argument 1 must be string, not None
```

:

```
def CleanUpFolder(dir):
    do = dir
    dir_with_original_files = dir
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(do):
        for d in dirs:
            for f in files:
                print f.title()
                if f.endswith('~'): #you don't want to process backups
                    continue
                original_file = os.path.join(root, f)
                with open(original_file, 'w') as orig_f, \
                    open(original_file, 'r') as orig_f2:
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(orig_f2.read())
                    for t in soup.find_all('td', class_='TEXT'):
                        t.string.wrap(soup.new_tag('h2'))

                # This is where you create your new modified file.
                    orig_f.write(soup.prettify().encode(soup.original_encoding))

CleanUpFolder('C:\Users\FOLDER')
```

What have I missed here? The main thing I am unsure about is how the line

```
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(do):
```

is used/made sense of in this context?

Comment: You don't need the recursive calls, *that's what `os.walk` is for*. Go back to basics; just run `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(do): print root, dirs, files` and see what happens.

Comment: Unless you're escaping your paths in actual code, the path being passed to your function is actually: `C:sersolder`. Make sure to either escape your paths, `'C:\\Users\\FOLDER'` or use a raw string, `r'C:\Users\FOLDER'`. Also, function names should never begin with a capital letter as others who see it will assume it's a `class` rather than a `function`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe OK, I have printed these, but I don't understand how this would prevent me from needing a recursive call. Would that not be neater?

Comment: Also and FWIW your error ("error on line 25, in CleanUpFolder") has obviously nothing to do with recursion ("obviously" for whoever take the few seconds required to actually read the error message, at least).

Comment: It's not about neatness; if you `walk` and also recursively call `CleanUpFolder` on the `dirs`, for a directory at depth `n` you clean it up `2 ** n` times!

Comment: "I don't understand how this would prevent me from needing a recursive call" => please read the documentation for `os.walk()`: it already recurse thru your directory tree - that the point of this function FWIW.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers makes a good point - your title refers to recursive calling but the only error you actually show seems unrelated to that. Which of the two code snippets causes it? Could you cut down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clarify what exactly the current problem is? For example, separating this into two functions (one to find appropriate files in the tree, one to clean them up) would help you pin down the source of the error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the responses, I have made an attempt with your comments regarding recursion in mind and updated my question. I've removed the older code (which I left to show my intent) to try and trim down superfluous information. Thanks for explaining iterating over filers/folders. Still encountering the same issue unfortunately but I think this is marginally closer?! :) Thanks.

Comment: Is that the actual indentation? You only seem to clean up the *last* `f in files`. However, again, the error seems unrelated to your looping over files; split this down into two more functions so you can test independently. Does this occur on the first file it reaches, or can some be processed correctly, for example?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's failing when it doesn't find the td with the correct class! Hence not accepting the none, so I just need a way to handle this :D. Thanks for your patience, sorry I am trying my best!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Although I don't understand why you say it is only editing the last file?

Comment: Still about the "real" error: `soup.prettify().encode("some-encoding-here")` won't do _exactly_ what you want: it will indeed encode the result of `soup.prettify()` to whatever encoding you pass, but you'll have a wrong encoding declared in your html "content-type" meta, cf  http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-encoding. You want 'soup.prettify("some-encoding-here"), and then no need to `.encode()` the result.

Comment: 1. Because of the indentation - `original_file = os.path.join(root, f)` is **outside** `for f in files:`. 2. It looks like you `open(original_file` in `'w'` mode **before** you open it in `'r'` mode, so it will always be empty and you'll never find what you want.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah, thanks for the first point. I messed up my indentation in the question and have fixed it now. I open the original file in w and r, but save it in different variables, so I should be able to do both, no? Unfortunately still getting the original error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have split your function up into two separate functions and cleared out redundant code:

```
def clean_up_folder(dir):
    """Run the clean up process on dir, recursively."""
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for f in files:
            print f.title()
            if not f.endswith('~'): #you don't want to process backups
                clean_up_file(os.path.join(root, f))
```

This has fixed the indentation problem, and will make it easier to test the functions and isolate any future errors. I have also removed the loop over `dirs`, as this will happen within `walk` anyway (and means you'd skip all `files` in any `dir` that doesn't contain any sub-`dirs`).

```
def clean_up_file(original_file):
    """Clean up the original_file."""      
    with open(original_file) as orig_f2:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(orig_f2.read())
    for t in soup.find_all('td', class_='TEXT'):
        t.string.wrap(soup.new_tag('h2'))
    with open(original_file, 'w') as orig_f:
        # This is where you create your new modified file.
        orig_f.write(soup.prettify().encode(soup.original_encoding))
```

Note that I have separated the two `open`s of `original_file` so you don't accidentally overwrite it before reading from it - there is no need to have it open for read and write simultaneously.

I don't have `BeautifulSoup` installed here, so can't test further, but this should allow you to narrow the issue down to a specific file.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, much appreciated :) Still suffering from the same error message as the OP, but it is much cleaner and nicer to work with. Thanks.

Comment: @SimonKiely this will make it much easier to do some actual testing and bugfinding and thereby ask a better question. Obvious question to ask yourself (or [your duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)) include: is this cleaning up the files you expect? Do those files contain what you expect? Does `soup.find_all` find what you expect? And so on...

Comment: if soup.original_encoding is not None:!!

You're brilliant @jonrsharpe , thank you :)

Comment: And thank you very much for having the patience to explain to me what I was doing incorrectly, I feel like I learned loads just from this post - thank you for that.

Comment: @SimonKiely not a problem. I think the key mistake you made was not any part of the code, but *trying to put it all together at once*. Divide and conquer - identify the parts of your idea that can be separate and build (and test!) one at a time. Here spotting that finding files to clean and cleaning them could be two separate processes more than halved the complexity.